# Jest test case updated the mocked data object for next test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, babel-jest

Helpers.spec.js file

```
describe('Helpers', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    jest.mock('./operations', () => ({
      Operators: jest.fn()
    }));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  const mockData = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ];

  it('Should return a id 1', async () => {
    Operations.getData = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockData);
    const response = await Helpers.execute();
    expect(response.id).toBe(1);
  });

  it('Should return a id 1 with true flag', async () => {
    Operations.getData = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockData);
    Operations.track = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({});

    const response = await Helpers.execute(true);
    expect(response.id).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Helpers.js

```
import { getData, track } from `./operations`;

export class Helpers {
  static async execute(request) {
    if(request)
      track();

    const data = getData();
    return data.shift();
  }
}
```

Operation.js

```
async function getData() {
  // Operation to return the data
}

async function track() {
  // Operation to track the data
}
```

Here Second test case is failing because it's returning the id 2. For some reason when second test case is running at that time `mockData` array has been shifted once because of first test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `const data = await getData()`, since `getData` function is `async`.
2. You should create the `mockData` for each test case so that the mutate it(`data.shift()`) in one test case will not affect other test cases.
3. Put the `jest.mock()` in module scope of the test file.

`helpers.js`:

```js
import { getData, track } from './operations';

export class Helpers {
    static async execute(request) {
        if (request) track();

        const data = await getData();
        return data.shift();
    }
}
```

`operations.js`:

```js
export async function getData() {
    // Operation to return the data
}

export async function track() {
    // Operation to track the data
}
```

`helpers.test.js`:

```js
import { Helpers } from './helpers';
import { getData, track } from './operations';

jest.mock('./operations');

describe('Helpers', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });


    it('Should return a id 1', async () => {
    const mockData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
        getData.mockResolvedValue(mockData);
        const response = await Helpers.execute();
        expect(response.id).toBe(1);
    });

    it('Should return a id 1 with true flag', async () => {
    const mockData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
        getData.mockResolvedValue(mockData);
        track.mockResolvedValue({});

        const response = await Helpers.execute(true);
        expect(response.id).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77265044/helpers.test.js (6.052 s)
  Helpers
    ✓ Should return a id 1 (1 ms)
    ✓ Should return a id 1 with true flag

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.261 s
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Lin Du. Actually I thought the same thing but here the actual mockData is too big and I have too many test cases. So in each and every test case I have to define the same const mockData is too lengthy. Because of that reason, I was looking for some alternative solutions. But thanks though. I have to apply same kinda solution like you mentioned.

Comment: @JayBhajiyawala You can declare it once, but clone it for each test case. This way will make your code shorter. The reason is the code mutates it.